# Let Java(JBoss) run on given timestamp, not synced from server (Windows). Only to be applied in test env

Tags: java, time, jboss

I'm trying to find a solution to my problem, which is only applicable in our test environments. I'm working with systems
(banking) depending on each system being on the same specific date. The development we do is solely within system integrations.
In short: Our systems generate the data, which we then adapt between our systems. Naturally, we do not hold the source 
codes to the systems we have.

To my specific problem: I have a system(A) running on JBoss: JBoss_4_2_3_GA on Java JRE build 1.6.0_32-b05. I've set up
a messaging broker in WebMethods(WM) listening to a specific port on this system. When users trigger certain events in system(A), JMS
topics are created and sent to a queue. WM then do a few validations and deliver the messages to system(B).
Everything was working properly, up until recently when we noticed that system(B) was expecting a timestamp field being
on the same date as the system itself were in (the functionality we built won’t otherwise work). The problem is that system(A) does not provide such a system date option,
and the timestamp in the messages are "real" timestamps from the operating system (Windows 2008 R2). So I require
a fake date (timestamp) applied in system(A) which would be on the same date as system(B).

The first solution to this problem was simply to disable the NTP sync and set a fake timestamp in Windows running
system(A), which would solve the date issue. But doing this, we noticed that our Windows group policies stopped working,
which affected normal logins to the server. So this was not a solution we could apply.

I know that others have posted this specific issue, and solutions such as using java date alternatives as Joda-Time etc.
I don't see how I can apply mentioned changes into my system(A) due to the lack of source code.
Help/suggestions would be greatfully appreciated. Right now I’m blindly focused into changing the timestamp in Java in system(A). Perhaps there are better alternatives such as just applying the fake date in WM? I just don’t know enough about WM to do this either.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I finally found a solution to my problem. Since the lack of source code, it was really a hard shot to do anything within the application (Java/JBoss). Searching arcoss forums, I found a nifty little tool (for Windows) called "RunAsDate". This tool does exactly what I need, as it intercepts the API calls to the OS related to dates and times and gives whatever date/timestamp the user chooses!
The best thing is that it doesn't make any changes to the system (dll's), and runs either from the simple GUI (in app package) or called from command line. Of course it will take arguments if required.
I hope others can find this as helpful as I do: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/run_as_date.html
BR
/rash